# Why 3 and 1 evaluates to 1 and 4 and 1 to 0 in nim-lang

Tags: logic, arithmetic-expressions, nim-lang

Hi I'm new to nim and dont get how evaluations of arithmetics work?

```
3 and 1 # Outputs 1
```

and

```
4 and 1 # Outputs 0
```

Which logic is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, in binary: 3 = 0b'11, 1 = 0b'01, so 3 and 1 = 0b'01, while 4 = 0b'100 and 1 = 0b'001, so 4 and 1 = 0b'00.

Comment: Wow! More obvious than I thought. Thanks